# Inner product and polynomials

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

> Let $V = \mathcal{P}_2$ (vector space of polynomials of degree not greater than two). We define the inner product on this space according to the formula
>   $$\langle \mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 \mathbf{p}\mathbf{q} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
>   Also consider the following two particular vectors
>   $$\mathbf{p} = 1 - x + 4x^2, \mathbf{q} = 1 + 4x - 3x^2.$$
>   The following questions are related to these vectors and the space
>
> a) Calculuate the inner product $\langle \mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}\rangle$.
>
> b) Calculate the distance between $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$.
>
> c) Calculate the norm $\|\mathbf{q}\|$, of the vector $\mathbf{q}$.

a) Am I correct in saying that the inner product $\langle p,q \rangle$ is $-24/5$?

b) Does the distance need to be a single number or an equation? For example $7x^2-5x$?

c) Again, I am not sure if this is right. Would $\|q\|$ be $26$?

Comment: The best way to learn MathJax is to click "Edit" on a post where the form is as you would like to write it yourself (for example the answer from Fred). Then you see the right syntax and can write it easier yourself later.

Comment: Hi Twigleg. Welcome to MSE! Thank you for trying to learn MathJax. Since you were struggling, I've formatted your question (and you can get the next one). As Nurator says, clicking "edit" (or "improve this question/answer") will allow you to play around with the Mathjax code used in questions and answers. Have a look at the particular commands I've used, and try playing around with them. Good luck!

Comment: P.S. braces { } are for grouping things in MathJax. For example `$x^{10}$` produces $x^{10}$, whereas `$x^10$` produces $x^10$. If you actually want braces, use `$\{ \}$`, which produces $\{ \}$.

Comment: Thank you, I replied to Fred and was able to modify my reply to use MathJax. I still think it will take me some time to get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

a) You are correct.

b) The distance is given by $||p-q||= \sqrt{<p-q,p-q>}= (\int_{-1}^1 (p(x)-q(x))^2dx)^{1/2}.$

c) $||q||= \sqrt{<q,q>}= (\int_{-1}^1 q(x)^2 dx)^{1/2}.$

Comment: I had a look through what you said, 
so is b) $\sqrt{544/15}$? 
and c) is $\sqrt{184/15}$?